# BigQuery Regex to get extract user between string and a character

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

```
{"sha":"65a0dbec42b65b6acc30dc1f814515c7c2174387","author":{"name":"Kubernetes Prow Robot","email":"5c2029016e1607554af814ace319699a11cecd88@users.noreply.github.com"},"message":"Merge pull request #97297 from saad-ali/automated-cherry-pick-of-#97259-upstream-release
```

I'm trying to extract the user in the github commit message.
In this example, it would return saad-ali
The user is always after the phrase `Merge pull request #97297 from` and the next `/`. The pull request # would be different from line to line though and the expression would need to work for any number.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular expression is possible:

```sql
SELECT *,
regexp_extract(A,r"request #\d* from ([^/]*)/") as B

from (
select """{"sha":"65a0dbec42b65b6acc30dc1f814515c7c2174387","author":{"name":"Kubernetes Prow Robot","email":"5c2029016e1607554af814ace319699a11cecd88@users.noreply.github.com"},"message":"Merge pull request #97297 from saad-ali/automated-cherry-pick-of-#97259-upstream-release
""" as A
)
```

For more complex question, JSON parsing would be a better option.